# Allow all remote connections, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I had been using SQL Server and am now using MySQL for a project. With SQL Server, our developers can connect to the remote database on their local machines if they know the host, username, password. With MySQL, though, to give a developer access from their local machines, I have been having to log in to MySQL and execute:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@address IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
flush privileges;
```

Where `address` is the IP address of the developer's machine. Of course, if they change networks, I have to execute it again. Is there a way to allow all remote connections like I have experienced with SQL Server, or is this a bad idea for some reason? We have username and password still.. I'm obviously a little confused.

Also: this is a development database and is only accessible from our internal network. I understand why it is a bad idea to give everyone access to a production database.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

As pointed out by Ryan above, the command you need is

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

However, note that the documentation indicates that in order for this to work, another user account from `localhost` must be created for the same user; otherwise, the anonymous account created automatically by `mysql_install_db` takes precedence because it has a more specific host column.

In other words; in order for user `user` to be able to connect from any server; 2 accounts need to be created as follows:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Read the full documentation [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

And here's the relevant piece for reference:

> After connecting to the server as root, you can add new accounts. The
>   following statements use GRANT to set up four new accounts:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost';
mysql> GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
mysql> CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
```

> The accounts created by these statements have the following
>   properties:
>
> Two of the accounts have a user name of monty and a password of
>   some_pass. Both accounts are superuser accounts with full privileges
>   to do anything. The 'monty'@'localhost' account can be used only when
>   connecting from the local host. The 'monty'@'%' account uses the '%'
>   wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any
>   host.
>
> **It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect
>   from anywhere as monty**. Without the localhost account, the
>   anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by
>   mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the
>   local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user.
>   The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more
>   specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes
>   earlier in the user table sort order. (user table sorting is discussed
>   in Section 6.2.4, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”.)

Answer (score 28):

You can disable all security by editing /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables

Answer (score 16):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Will allow a specific user to log on from anywhere.

It's bad because it removes some security control, i.e. if an account is compromised.

Comment: One more thing I had to do change was TCP bind interface. Since i had to connect to a mysql instance hosted in cloud , I changed "bind-address=0.0.0.0" in /etc/mysql/my.cnf , default is 127.0.0.1 where mysql listens only on local loopback interface and doesnt take calls from outside networks.

Comment: I have been struggling to figure out how to connect from anywhwere and these soltuions just helped me solve that initial problem. Many thanks but I have run into a different problem.

I have tried to change the port number from 80 to 8080. Now, when I use http://servername:8080/mysite it quickly reverts back to http://servername/mysite gives a 404 - file or directory not found error. How do I make it work with port 8080?

Great stuff

Comment: @Kenny, create a new question

Answer (score 15):

> Install and setup mysql to connect from anywhere remotely **DOES NOT
>   WORK WITH mysql_secure_installation !**
>   (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html)

## On Ubuntu, Install mysql using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

## Have just the below in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#### Unix socket settings (making localhost work)
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

#### TCP Socket settings (making all remote logins work)
port            = 3306
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

## Login into DB from server using

mysql -u root -p

## Create DB user using the below statement

```
grant all privileges on *.* to ‘username’@‘%’ identified by ‘password’;
```

## Open firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

## Restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: if anything, `grant all privileges on *.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password';`... but anyway doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'192.168.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'192.168.%.%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you need to disable below line in configuration file:
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

**Mabey you only need:**

**Step one:**

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'IP' identified by 'password';
```

or

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

**Step two:**

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

**Step three:**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```