# MySQL and C# connection error

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect my c# program to my website database. When i run the program and click the button to activate the connection the try catch block catches this error.

[image]

```
server = "MY WEBSITE IP,PORT";
database = "DATABASE NAME";
uid = "USER FOR THE DATABASE";
password = "PASSWORD FOR THE USER";

try
{
    string myConnection = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE FancyDatabase;",myConn);

    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myConn.Open();
    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myConn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: It is not a code problem. You need to give permission at your user to connect from the specific computer

Comment: I already have given the user all privileges in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change mysql config, to allow connections from your computer (your ip address). By default it's allowed only to have local connections to the server.

Comment: how do i allow it to receive connections from any ip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql
You need to connect to your server from localhost and run commands that are listed in the above url.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message sais it all. Access is denied for the user.

Make sure you use the correct uid and password. If uid and password is correct, access is not configured properly in the server.

Answer (score 0):

At your hosting, you can add the server "% " to allow other ip-addresses to connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution:**

```
string myConnection = " datasource=IP;port=3306;username=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;";
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from
```