# Create new Mysql user which can be accessed from any end point

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create new user on my Mysql database.
The user should be a accessed from any end point and have all privileges.

Actually, I can't understand what is the meaning of the host column in my mysql.user table.

Which sql statement I need to write for this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to check is that your mysql server can receive connection from the outside. So check in `my.ini` config file the value of `bind-address` property.

Tipically you have to change it from

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Then restart your server.

Now you can add your user specifying the wildcard character `%` for host column. This allow your specified user from any host to your setted privileges.

Then you can create your user:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'192.168.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and grand privileges on schemas/tables:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Instead of grant ALL privileges, you can grant:

`CREATE` - allows them to create new tables or databases

`DROP` - allows them to them to delete tables or databases

`DELETE` - allows them to delete rows from tables

`INSERT` - allows them to insert rows into tables

`SELECT` - allows them to use the Select command to read through databases

`UPDATE` -  allow them to update table rows

`GRANT OPTION` - allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges

At the end flush your privileges: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

The general syntax of GRANT is:

```
GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;
```

You can use a tool like [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to simplify this task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In /etc/mysql tipically

Comment: can't find it there.. any place else ?

Comment: find / -name my.cnf  ..or try my.ini

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor which distro are you using? are you installing mysql from distro package installer (apt / emerge / ..) or from sources?

Comment: The mysql is already been installed.
Now I need to create new user that I can access him from anywhere.

Isn't it just a simple sql statement ?