# SQL connection : can't connect to database in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp, database-connection

I have added JAR file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin" and have created database "UserScore" and under that table "ScoreSheet".I have added a row in ScoreSheet (Name,Score) value ('Kamal',40) to verify but the code throws a lot of exceptions on connection.I am using Eclipse + Xampp.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class SQLDriver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            //Accessing driver from jar file
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Get connection through creating a variable 'myConn'
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserScores");

            //Create statement
            PreparedStatement statement = myConn.prepareStatement("select * from 'scoresheet'");

            //Execute SQL Query
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            //Process the result set
            while(result.next()){
                System.out.println(result.getString(1)+" "+result.getString(2));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are those exceptions ??

Comment: Paste your exceptions here

Comment: `but the code throws a lot of exceptions on connection`. Please mention those

Comment: There is an error in your query. I think you meant `select * from scoresheet;`.

Comment: "select * from **'scoresheet'**"?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4al4gaaayyrs755/Screenshot%202015-07-27%2023.36.54.png?dl=0

Comment: In Xampp it's written as - select * from 'scoresheet'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do  it like this:

```
// Hostname
private static final String dbHost = "127.0.0.1";

// Port -- Standard: 3306
private static final String dbPort = "3306";

// Database name
private static String database = "database"; //

// Database user
private static final String dbUser = "root";

// Datenbankpasswort
private static final String dbPassword = "";

private Statement s;


public void Connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver"); // load driver
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":"
                + dbPort + "/" + database + "?" + "user=" + dbUser + "&"
                + "password=" + dbPassword); // try to connect with your attributes 
        s = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { // 
        l.error("Driver not found " + e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        l.error("Connect not possible" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced localhost to 127.0.0.1 but didn't work out, rest is logically same I guess.

Comment: was there an exception ?

Comment: lots....but I think the number got reduced...so I am sharing screenshot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwr4m3mefd2yn7p/Screenshot%202015-07-28%2000.23.59.png?dl=0

Comment: okay the problem is that your user is not allowed to connect to the database. you have to allow the connection. you can do this with phpmyadmin or with sql commands : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql for example

Comment: Thanks  user4139197. I created a new user with custom privileges.

Answer (score 0):

- Your query should specify `Scoresheet` without `'`
- Specify the username and password when calling `DriverManager.getConnection`
- The second row in your table does not appear to be of type string. Invoke `result.getInt(2)` rather than `result.getString(2)`

Comment: Haven't set any username/password to my database and I followed your first and last point but it didn't work out.

Comment: @KamalVidhani Judging by the screenshot you posted, it appears MySQL is not running.

Comment: "MySQL is not running" means?

Comment: @KamalVidhani Exactly what it says. You can start it like this, assuming you're on a Windows system: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html