# Can not connect to database sonarqube with mysql in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, sonarqube

I try to install sonarqube with mysql in docker.

1. Mysql

```

```
$ docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --name mysql mysql
$ docker exec -it mysql bash
# mysql -uroot -proot
mysql> CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8;
mysql> CREATE USER 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

```

2. SonarQube

```

```
$ docker run -d --name SonarQube --link mysql:mysql -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 \
-e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
-e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
-e "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true" \
  sonarqube
```

```

Here is my error log.
Give me a solution.
Thankyou

`2018.08.10 12:53:37 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change host in JDBC URL environment variable to below i.e replace `localhost` with `mysql` -

```
-e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
```

Reason being you created a link to container `mysql` with DNS name `mysql` which means it will put a host entry for mysql container IP in sonarqube container. You can verify it by doing a `docker exec` & `cat /etc/hosts` in sonarqube container. That's how linking works w.r.t docker in the background.

PS - Localhost means the container itself & not the mysql container.

**Update**

Your second issue is, you are granting privileges for `@'localhost'` which means access from sonarqube container will be denied, you can change it to `@'%'` to allow from anywhere.

Ref - [MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)
[Allow all remote connections, MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql)

Comment: Thank you your answer. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Destroy all the containers & start fresh. It's supposed to work. If it doesn't post the `/etc/hosts` contents in your question after linking.

Comment: root@9b5ddc2ee125:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3      9b5ddc2ee125

Comment: It doesn't have a entry for mysql container. I have tried this & it has worked for me. Ref - `--link=""  : Add link to another container (<name or id>:alias or <name or id>)`

Doc - https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#start-a-mysql-server-instance

Comment: I don't see any other issue here. I built it from scratch in my env & it's working for me.

Comment: Updated the answer. I tried to reproduce it & found a permission issue as well, have suggested a solution, give it a shot.

Comment: I have not solved it yet. But I understood your answer. THX