# Connecting to external Mysql database from AWS lambda (back end of Alexa skill) returns "Access denied for user" message

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing an Alexa lambda function in Javascript to connect to my external database.  I have successfully accessed that database with the same username and password.  I have uploaded the mysql code from the noded_modules folder on my laptop.  Here is the Javascript code:

```
        var mysql = require('mysql');

        var con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "www.oryxtech.net",
          user: "",
          password: "" 
        });

        con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Connected!");
        });
```

and this is the error message from the lambda console:

```
2020-01-03T23:08:10.885Z    1100009f-24bf-4980-a2e1-27044988eb9d    Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'oryxtech_sideE'@'ec2-3-85-146-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/task/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/var/task/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at mysqlDB.init (/var/task/mysqlDB.js:17:13)
    at getWelcomeResponse (/var/task/index.js:64:19)
    at onLaunch (/var/task/index.js:263:5)
    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:328:13)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a step I have omitted?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the user `oryxtech_sideE` is not granted permission to access the database from host `ec2-3-85-146-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. Please confirm the same.

You can grant the user to access the host

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'oryxtech_sideE'@'ec2-3-85-146-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or any host:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'oryxtech_sideE'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Reference:
[Allow all remote connections, MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql)

Hope this helps.